Obtain moments of random variable $X$ given $E_X[\log(1+e t X)]$
Suppose I have a random variable $X$ for which I know that
$$E_X[\log(1+e t X)]=W_0(t)$$
Where $W_0$ is the Lambert W function and $e$ is e.
I'm interested in generating a plot of $g(s)=E[X^s]$ as a function of $s>1$. Any tips appreciated!
Background
Origin of this is that I have a random matrix $A$, and I need to find symmetric moments, $g(s)=\operatorname{Tr}(A^{s/2} (A^{s/2})^t)$. This can be formulated as $E[X^s]$ where distribution of $X$ is the distribution of singular values of $X$. The "mysterious" density is the distribution of singular values of matrix described in the following mathoverflow question
Sorted singular values (aka, Survival Function of random variable $X$) looks like below

It's an open problem to characterize behavior of moments of this density, but s^s/(Gamma[s + 1]*Exp[s] seems like a good guess, both LambertW and s^s/(Gamma[s + 1]*Exp[s] have been obtained heuristically
notebook
ClearAll["Global`*"];
d = 1024;
m = d;
ii = IdentityMatrix[d];
A = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[], {m, d}];

SF = StringForm;
gdOp = ii - 1/(4 d) A\[Transpose] . A;
sgdOp = Fold[Function[{A, v}, Table[w - v (w . v), {w, A}]], ii, 
   Normalize /@ A];

observedPlot = 
  ListPlot[{SingularValueList@sgdOp, SingularValueList@gdOp}, 
   PlotLabel -> 
    SF["i'th largest Singular Value of \!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(A\), \(``\
\)]\)", d], AxesLabel -> {"i", "singular value"}, 
   PlotLegends -> {"sgdOp", "gdOp"}];

predictedPlot = 
  Plot[1 - 
    SurvivalFunction[MarchenkoPasturDistribution[1], 4 - t/(d/4)], {t,
     0, d}, PlotStyle -> Dashed, PlotLegends -> {"MP predicted"}];

Show[observedPlot, predictedPlot]


Did I understand correctly,you want to solve: Solve[{Expectation[x^s, x \[Distributed] Y] == g[s],    Expectation[Log[1 + E t x], x \[Distributed] Y] ==     ProductLog[0, t]}, {g[s], Y}] where Y is unknown distribution ?

Now with @A.Kato 's  great answer, what can you do with the moments?  With the moments getting smaller with increasing values of $s$, does that not suggest that $X$ has maybe finite support in the interval (0, 1) ?  The skewness is slightly positive and the kurtosis is much less than a normal distribution.  Do you not really need the distribution of $X$ rather than the moments?  I wasn't successful in getting a nice result for the moment generating function which might help identify a distribution for $X$.

@MariuszIwaniuk yes, that's correct. yarchik's solution with SeriesCoefficient seems to be able to solve this

Conjecture
$$g (s) = \frac {s^s} {e^s \Gamma (s + 1)}$$
My key idea is to expand everything as Taylor series around $t=0$.
The above prediction is based on the following set of MMA results.
Clear["Global`*"];    
nmax = 10;
sa = Series[Log[1 + Exp[1]*t*X], {t, 0, nmax}]


Taylor Series of the Lambert function $W_{0}(t)$:
sb = Series[ProductLog[t], {t, 0, nmax}]


Equate the coefficients of $t^n$ in these series and solve for $g(n)=\mathbf{E}[X^n]$:
tab = Table[
  g[n] -> SeriesCoefficient[sb, n]/SeriesCoefficient[sa, n] /. 
   X -> 1, {n, 1, nmax}]


In order to obtain a general formula for $g(n)$, I wanted to clear the denominator of $g(n)$, so tried multiplying by $n!$:
Table[n!*(g[n] /. tab), {n, 1, nmax}]


Hooray! The numerators look like $n^n$. Let's confirm this:
tab2 = Table[g[n] -> n^n/(n! Exp[n]), {n, 1, nmax}]


tab == tab2

(* True *)

To obtain a formula for $\mathbf{E}[X^s]$ for general $s$, we need to rewrite the factorial using $\Gamma$ function:
tab3 = 
 Table[g[s] -> s^s/(Gamma[s + 1]*Exp[s]), {s, 1, nmax}]

tab == tab3

(* True *)

I'm confident that the conjecture is true, but I used some formal manipulation --- which is rigorously justified or not, I don't know.

Automating the solution of A. Kato:
Assuming[n > 0, 
 Simplify[
  Solve[SeriesCoefficient[ProductLog[t], {t, 0, n}] == 
      SeriesCoefficient[Log[1 + Exp[1]*t*X], {t, 0, n}] /. {X^n -> g[n]}, g[n]] // First]]

(* {g[n] -> (E^-n n^n)/n!} *)


Given what you've currently stated, I think there are an infinite number of random variables that qualify.  Here is one example with $t=4$:
dist = TransformedDistribution[Log[1 + Exp[1] t  x], 
   x \[Distributed] GammaDistribution[α, β]];

mean = Mean[dist /. {α -> 1, t -> 4}] // FullSimplify
(* -E^((1/(4 E β))) ExpIntegralEi[-(1/(4 E β))] *)

FindRoot[mean == LambertW[4], {{β, 1}}]
(* {β -> 0.296819} *)

And another with $t=4$:
mean = Mean[dist /. {α -> 1/2, t -> 4}] // FullSimplify
(* 1 - EulerGamma + π Erfi[1/(2 Sqrt[E] Sqrt[β])] - 
 HypergeometricPFQ[{1, 1}, {3/2, 2}, 1/(4 E β)]/(2 E β) + Log[β] *)

FindRoot[mean == LambertW[4], {{β, 1}}]
(* {β -> 0.788784} *)

But if you are interested a single distribution where the desired condition is satisfied for all $t>0$, then that should be made explicit.

Indeed, I was looking for all $t>0$

Got it.  I look forward for someone providing a technique to get you an answer.  Do you have any more information about the target distribution other than the mean of that transformed value?  Or even something more about the transformed random variable?

Given @A.Kato 's excellent answer that addressed your question about the moments, I'm exploring here about the actual distribution of $X$ (which you didn't explicitly ask about).
That the raw moments $g(s)$ tend to zero with increasing values of $s$ is consistent with the positive density of $X$ being bounded and a subset of the integrval (0, 1).  The skewness is positive and the kurtosis much less than a normal distribution (3):
variance = ((x - g[1])^2 // Expand) /. {x^k_ -> g[k], x -> g[1]} // FullSimplify
(* 1/E^2 *)
skeweness = (((x - g[1])^3 // Expand)  /. {x^k_ -> g[k], x -> g[1]})/ variance^(3/2) // FullSimplify
(* 1/2 *)
kurtosis = (((x - g[1])^4 // Expand) /. {x^k_ -> g[k], x -> g[1]})/ variance^2//N
(* 1.66667 *)

Consider a beta random variable with first and second moments that match A.Kato's answer:
dist = BetaDistribution[a, b];
{a0, b0} = {a, b} /. Solve[{Mean[dist] == g[1], Moment[dist, 2] == g[2]}, {a, b}][[1]]
(* {(-2 + E)/E, (2 - 3 E + E^2)/E} *)

We can now plot the moments for both distributions for $s=1,2,\ldots,50$:
t = Table[{s, g[s] // N, Moment[dist /. {a -> a0, b -> b0}, s] // N}, {s, 1, 50}]);
ListPlot[{t[[All, {1, 2}]], t[[All, {1, 3}]]}, PlotRange -> All,
 PlotLegends -> {"Mysterious X distribution", "Beta distribution"},
 Frame -> True, FrameLabel -> (Style[#, Bold, 18, Italic] &) /@ {"s", "g(s)"},
 PlotStyle -> {PointSize[0.02], PointSize[0.01]}, ImageSize -> Large]


We can see that the mysterious $X$ random variable doesn't have a beta distribution but it seems that a beta distribution might be a reasonable approximation to the distribution of $X$.
A plot of that beta distribution follows:
Plot[PDF[BetaDistribution[a0, b0], x], {x, 0, 1}, 
  PlotRange -> {All, {0, 3}}, Frame -> True,
  FrameLabel -> {Style["Y \[Distributed] BetaDistribution(\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(a\), \(0\)]\), \!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(b\), \(0\)]\))", Bold, Italic, 18] 
  Style["Probability density", Bold, 18]}]



interesting connection to Beta. I've added "background" section to show what this "mysterious density" represents

btw, the right side doesn't matter, it only affects values for very small $s$. So p(x)=O(x^\alpha) for some value of alpha should form a good approximation of the density
